# Initializing a Generic variable from a C# Type Variable

Tags: c#, generics

I have a class that takes a Generic Type as part of its initialization.

```
public class AnimalContext<T>
{
    public DoAnimalStuff()
    {
        //AnimalType Specific Code
    }
}
```

What I can do right now is

```
AnimalContext<Donkey> donkeyContext = new AnimalContext<Donkey>();
AnimalContext<Orca> orcaContext = new AnimalContext<Orca>();
```

But what I need/want to do is be able to declare an AnimalContext initialized to a type that is only known at runtime.  For instance,

```
Animal a = MyFavoriteAnimal(); //returns an instance of a class 
                               //implementing an animal
AnimalContext<a.GetType()> a_Context = new AnimalContext<a.GetType()>();
a_Context.DoAnimalStuff();
```

Is this even possible? I can't seem to find an answer for this online.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

What you mean by this part *is* possible:

```
new AnimalContext<a.GetType()>();
```

Obviously that exact syntax is wrong, and we'll get to that, but it *is* possible to construct an instance of a generic type at *runtime* when you don't know the type parameters until *runtime*.

What you mean by this part is *not*:

```
AnimalContext<a.GetType()> a_Context
```

That is, it is impossible to type a variable as a generic type if you don't know the type parameters at *compile-time*. Generics are *compile-time* constructs, and rely on having the type information available at *compile-time*. Given this, you lose all the benefits of generics if you don't know the types at compile-time.

Now, to construct an instance of a generic type at runtime when you don't know the type until runtime, you can say:

```
var type = typeof(AnimalContext<>).MakeGenericType(a.GetType());
var a_Context = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Note that the *compile-time* type of `a_context` is `object`. You will have to cast `a_context` to a type or interface that defines the methods you need to access. Often what you'll see people do here is have the generic type `AnimalContext<T>` implement some interface (say `IAnimalContext`) *or* inherit from a non-generic base class (say `AnimalContext`) that defines the methods they need (so then you can cast `a_context` to the interface or the non-generic base class). Another alternative is to use `dynamic`. But again, keep in mind, you have *none* of the benefits of generic types in doing this.

Comment: Everyone who answered gave an answer that provided a bit more information than the previous answer. All were correct, and excellent in quality, but only one can be selected as The Answer, so I chose this one which was the most descriptive. I would like to thank everyone who answered though, and I appreciate all the assistance (specially late on a Sunday night.)

Comment: What if my Class is not generic but the inside Method is, How will i use the MakeGenericType in that case

Comment: By far the most useful answer ever about c# generics.
After hours of research this saved so much time.
Thank you so much

Answer (score 13):

You can use reflection with generic type by using [`MakeGenericType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx) method and take adavantage of `dynamic` keyword:

```
var type = typeof (AnimalContext<>).MakeGenericType(a.GetType());
dynamic a_Context = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

So you can call:

```
a_Context.DoAnimalStuff();
```

Or use reflection again to call method:

```
type.GetMethod("DoAnimalStuff").Invoke(a_Context, null);
```

Answer (score 6):

You would need to create the type using Reflection and then invoke that type. Something like:

```
Animal a = MyFavoriteAnimal();
var contextType = typeof(EsbRepository<>).MakeGenericType(a.GetType());

dynamic context = Activator.CreateInstance(contextType);
context.DoAnimalStuff();
```

The use of dynamic means that the context variable will be evaluated at run time allowing for you to call the DoAnimalStuff method.