# How to use local variable as a type? Compiler says "it is a variable but is used like a type"

Tags: c#, reflection

At run-time, I don't know what type of variable `v1` is.
For this reason, I wrote many `if else` statements:

```
if (v1 is ShellProperty<int?>)
{
    v2 = (v1 as ShellProperty<int?>).Value;
}
else if (v1 is ShellProperty<uint?>)
{
    v2 = (v1 as ShellProperty<uint?>).Value;
}
else if (v1 is ShellProperty<string>)
{
    v2 = (v1 as ShellProperty<string>).Value;
}
else if (v1 is ShellProperty<object>)
{
    v2 = (v1 as ShellProperty<object>).Value;
}
```

The only difference is in `ShellProperty<AnyType>`.

So instead of writing this with a lot of `if else` statements, I decided to use reflection to get the property type at run-time:

```
 Type t1 = v1.GetType().GetProperty("Value").PropertyType;
 dynamic v2 = (v1 as ShellProperty<t1>).Value;
```

This code gets the `PropertyType` of `v1` and assigns it to the local variable `t1`, but after that, my compiler says that:

> t1 is a variable but is used like a type

So it does not allow me to write `t1` inside `ShellProperty<>`.

Please tell me how to solve this problem and how to get more compact code than what I have. Do I need to create a new class?

Comment: You can't use generics in that way.  Generics are strongly typed at compile time.

Comment: So you mean it is not possible

Comment: not statically like this. but you are already doing dynamic.

Comment: Not using dyanmic objects.  If your value is an object (i.e. inherits from System.Object or better yet some base class that you own), you could do `object v2 = v1 as ShellProperty<t1>`.  (Again, using your own base class--or better yet an interface--would make this more useful.)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You were very close, you were just missing a call to `MakeGenericType`.

I believe your code would look like the following:

```
Type t1 = v1.GetType().GetProperty("Value").PropertyType;
var shellPropertyType = typeof(ShellProperty<>);
var specificShellPropertyType = shellPropertyType.MakeGenericType(t1);
dynamic v2 = specificShellPropertyType.GetProperty("Value").GetValue(v1, null);
```

Edit:
As @PetSerAl pointed out I added some layers of indirection that were unnecessary. Sorry OP, you probably want a one liner like:

```
dynamic v2 = v1.GetType().GetProperty("Value").GetValue(v1, null);
```

Comment: Is that: `v1.GetType().GetProperty("Value").GetValue(v1, null)` not enough?

Comment: @PetSerAl You're absolutely right, I feel very silly. I spent too much time looking at the original code and not enough time thinking about my answer. I will update now.

Comment: very funny! maybe @PetSerAl is right! But anyway this was for "How to use Local variable as a type?"

Comment: I believe this was not for the question "How to use Local variable as a type?" as i get the same error...

Answer (score 17):

For generics, you have to create them dynamically.

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(Sample).GetMethod("GenericMethod");
MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(myType);
generic.Invoke(this, null);
```

To create a generic object, you can

```
var type = typeof(ShellProperty<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(SomeObject));
var v2 = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Please refer to [Initializing a Generic variable from a C# Type Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17519078/initializing-a-generic-variable-from-a-c-sharp-type-variable)