# Passing type as variable and then using it

Tags: c#

I want to be able do something like this

```cs
void SampleFunction(Type type)
{
    type varA = default(type);
    OtherGenericFunction<type>();
}
```

Tried using `typeof(type)` but it didn't gave any result.

I tried searching it, but did not understand solutions or how to apply them, these I looked:

[How to use local variable as a type?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32935388/10734516)

[Passing just a type as a parameter in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10955608/10734516)

Can someone explain how to deal with situation in my case?

Just to give some context: I trying to mock some generic functions. As straightforward mock of generic doesn't working - my current theoretical solution is to gather `List<Type>` of used types in function Im testing, then just iterate through it and setup my mock object.

Comment: `Void SampleFunction<T>() { OtherGenericFunction<T>(); }`?

Comment: If you *absolutely must* do this, you need to use reflection; in particular `openGenericMethod.MakeGenericMethod(type).Invoke(...)` where `openGenericMethod` is what you get from `type.GetMethod("OtherGenericFunction")`. It is inefficient, though; fine for mocking/testing, I guess

Comment: Thanks, both comments helped me to form a little more stable picture of whats happening

Comment: Why don't you include your actual code and which mocking framework you use?