# Net Core: Declare New DbContext with a Variable Type

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

How do I declare DbContextOptionsBuilder, where the DbContext is stored in a variable (in this case real name of dbContext is "OnlineShoppingStore" but stored in the two variables below.

```
var dbContextType = dbContextAssembly.GetTypes().Where(d => d.BaseType.Name == "DbContext").First();
var businessDbContext = Activator.CreateInstance(dbContextType) as DbContext;
DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder();

// Attempting Line Below
var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<dbContextType>().UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "Test").Options;
```

> Error: dbContextType is a variable but is used like a type.

**End Goal** is to declare a new DbContext, given the type from the assembly above.

Example:

```
var onlineStoreContext = new OnlineStoreContext(options)
```

Comment: Can you use the non-generic version of `DbContextOptionsBuilder`?

Comment: how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. You can create an instance of Generic Type using:

```
Type dbContextType = typeof(MyDbContext);
// 1st get type of Generic object
Type dbContextOptionsBuilderType = typeof(DbContextOptionsBuilder<>);
// 2nd call "MakeGenericType" method by passing the "T" type
Type dbContextOptionsBuilderGenericType = dbContextOptionsBuilderType.MakeGenericType(dbContextType);
// 3rd create an instance by using "Activator.CreateInstance"
DbContextOptionsBuilder dbContextOptionsBuilderInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(dbContextOptionsBuilderGenericType) as DbContextOptionsBuilder;

DbContextOptions dbContextOptions = dbContextOptionsBuilderInstance.UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "Test").Options;
```

"[How to use local variable as a type? Compiler says "it is a variable but is used like a type"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32935297/how-to-use-local-variable-as-a-type-compiler-says-it-is-a-variable-but-is-used)" is the original solution.

Comment: can you link it to the assembly statements? I am trying to run the first statement on one of my assemblies dbContextType, is not working, same error

Comment: Type test = typeof(dbContextType)

Comment: trying to run the last statement also new businessDbContext(dbContextOptions)

Comment: need to instantiate the dbContext also with its options

Comment: Tried with this and it worked fine for me

            Assembly dbContextAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

            var dbContextType = dbContextAssembly.GetTypes()
                .Where(p => p.BaseType.Name == "DbContext")
                .First();

Comment: I just need a connecting link to the assembly dbcontext 'dbcontextype' or business dbcontext

Comment: how to I pass dbContextOptions to the db context as a parameter?

Comment: using Activator.CreateInstance

Activator.CreateInstance(dbContextType, dbContextOptions);