# Casting of generic type T to List<> for list equality checking

Tags: c#, list, generics, casting

I have a generic method `Compare` which receives two input parameters of type `T` in the signature and compares them for equality.  A boolean is returned.  The logic is fairly straight forward for 'ordinary' c# .net types.

However, the generic type `T` can also be a `List<U>` (e.g. `List<int> xList` and `List<int> yList`), which I would like to compare for equality.  I do not know the type of `U` at compile time, but can obtain it dynamically as shown in the example below.

I'm trying to use `Enumerable.SequenceEqual<V>()`, for list comparison, but this method needs to know the type of  at compile time.  To circumnavigate this, I've tried to dynamically cast the `T` to `List<U>`, but without success.  An error is thrown at runtime (indicated in the code snippet).

Is there an elegant way of doing a list comparison as attempted below, where the list internal type is not known at compile time?  The closest I could come to an answer is here: [How to use local variable as a type? Compiler says "it is a variable but is used like a type"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32935297/how-to-use-local-variable-as-a-type-compiler-says-it-is-a-variable-but-is-used), and it seems awfully close to what I need, but I could not leverage this to a successful solution.

```
public bool Compare(T x, T y)
{
    bool isEqual;

    if (typeof(T).IsSubClassOfGenericBaseType(typeof(List<>)))
    {

        Type listElementType = 
            x.GetType().GetGenericArguments().Single();
        Type specificListType = (typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(listElementType));
        dynamic xList = x.GetType().MakeGenericType(specificListType);  // <-- Exception is thrown here.
        dynamic yList = y.GetType().MakeGenericType(specificListType);

        isEqual = Enumerable.SequenceEqual(xList, yList);
    }
    else
    {
        isEqual = EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(x, y);
    }            

    return isEqual;
}
```

The `Type` extension method `IsSubClassOfGenericBaseType` are as follows:

```
internal static bool IsSubClassOfGenericBaseType(
            this Type type, Type genericBaseType)
{
    if (   type.IsGenericType 
        && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == genericBaseType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (type.BaseType != null)
    {
        return IsSubClassOfGenericBaseType(
            type.BaseType, genericBaseType);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: If you fine with `dynamic` why you have all that code - `Enumerable.SequenceEqual((dynamic)x, (dynamic)y)` should be plenty enough, maybe with some extra type checking first (`x.GetType() == y.GetType()`)... Or maybe you are asking about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method?

Comment: Thanks @AlexeiLevenkov.  I would prefer not having dynamic in there, but is there a way to do it without dynamic?

Comment: I'm obviously out of ideas as neither `dynamic` nor calling generic method via reflection as shown in the link I gave is not what you need... Sorry.

Comment: How are you calling `Compare()`? Could you have an overload that accepts a `List<T>`?

Comment: Hi @MatthewWatson.  I have a class called ```DetailedProperty```, with three properties being ```T Value```, ```T DefaultValue``` and ```bool IsDefaultValue```.  The ```get``` method on ```IsDefaultValue``` is set to the ```Compare``` method above.  Hence, if ```T``` is of type ```List<>```, I want to be able to compare it for equality to return ```true``` or ```false``` through the ```IsDefaultValue``` property.  @AlexeiLevenkov 's proposal for the use of ```dynamic``` works.  I think it would be more elegant if I could get away from the ```dynamic```.  But I'm open to be corrected.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by that code line which throws the exception. `x.GetType()` is already a fully constructed ("closed") generic type, why are you attempting to do `MakeGenericType` on it? Like Alexei says, if you are OK with `dynamic`, what happens if you do simply `if (typeof(T).IsSubClassOfGenericBaseType(typeof(List<>))) { isEqual = Enumerable.SequenceEqual((dynamic)x, (dynamic)y); }`? Alexei's other suggestion, to use `MakeGenericMethod` then `Invoke` seems to be good if you want to avoid `dynamic` but are OK with reflection. So consider Alexei's first comment again.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen.  Indeed a valid comment.  I misunderstood what ```MakeGenericType``` would do.  I thought it would cast the T to its own type so that the ```SequenceEqual``` method could register the type and do the comparison.  Nonetheless, the solution provided by @MatthewWatson solves the question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would something like this work for you?

```
public static bool Compare(object? x, object? y)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(x, y))
        return true;

    if (x is null || y is null)
        return false;

    if (x is IEnumerable a && y is IEnumerable b)
        return a.Cast<object>().SequenceEqual(b.Cast<object>());

    return x.Equals(y);
}
```

Usage:

```
var a = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
var b = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
var c = new List<int> { 1, 2, 4 };
var d = new List<bool>{ true, false, true };
var e = "string";
var f = new Collection<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
var g = new List<short> { 1, 2, 3 };

Console.WriteLine(Compare(a, b)); // True
Console.WriteLine(Compare(a, c)); // False
Console.WriteLine(Compare(a, d)); // False
Console.WriteLine(Compare(a, e)); // False
Console.WriteLine(Compare(a, f)); // True - might not be what you want,
Console.WriteLine(Compare(a, g)); // False

Console.ReadLine();
```

Note that because I'm using `SequenceEqual()` (as per your suggestion) then the `List<int>` compares true to the equivalent `Collection<int>`. I think this is probably what you want, since a `List<int>` *is* a `Collection<int>`, but just so you are aware.

Also note that you shouldn't call the method `Compare()` in your code - it might cause people to confuse it with [`IComparer.Compare()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.icomparer.compare?view=net-5.0).

Do be aware that this solution is likely to be significantly slower than just doing:

```
public static bool CompareDynamic<T>(T x, T y)
{
    return typeof(T).IsSubClassOfGenericBaseType(typeof(List<>)) 
        ? Enumerable.SequenceEqual((dynamic)x, (dynamic)y) 
        : EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(x, y);
}
```

This is due to all the casting (and hence boxing, if the elements are value types). If there are few elements, then it won't matter much but for large collections that could be a problem.

---

For completeness, here is some benchmark code that compares the performance of casting versus using dynamic for a fairly large `int` list:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Jobs;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Running;

namespace Demo
{
    [SimpleJob(RuntimeMoniker.Net50)]
    public class Program
    {
        List<int> a = Enumerable.Range(1, 100_000).ToList();
        List<int> b = Enumerable.Range(1, 100_000).ToList();

        static void Main()
        {
            BenchmarkRunner.Run<Program>();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public void ViaCompareCast()
        {
            CompareCast(a, b);
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public void ViaCompareDynamic()
        {
            CompareDynamic(a, b);
        }

        public static bool CompareCast(object? x, object? y)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(x, y))
                return true;

            if (x is null || y is null)
                return false;

            if (x is IEnumerable a && y is IEnumerable b)
                return a.Cast<object>().SequenceEqual(b.Cast<object>());

            return x.Equals(y);
        }

        public static bool CompareDynamic<T>(T x, T y)
        {
            return IsSubClassOfGenericBaseType(typeof(T), typeof(List<>)) 
                ? Enumerable.SequenceEqual((dynamic)x, (dynamic)y) 
                : EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(x, y);
        }

        static bool IsSubClassOfGenericBaseType(Type type, Type genericBaseType)
        {
            if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == genericBaseType)
                return true;

            if (type.BaseType != null)
                return IsSubClassOfGenericBaseType(type.BaseType, genericBaseType);

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The results (for a .net 5.0 release build) are as follows:

```
|            Method |       Mean |    Error |    StdDev |     Median |
|------------------ |-----------:|---------:|----------:|-----------:|
|    ViaCompareCast | 4,930.6 us | 96.79 us | 191.04 us | 4,832.1 us |
| ViaCompareDynamic |   667.6 us | 12.67 us |  28.07 us |   652.7 us |
```

As you can see, the version using `dynamic` is **more than 70 times faster** for this particular data set. So you pays your money and you makes your choice!

Comment: Thanks so much @MatthewWatson.  This is exactly what I was looking for, making the ```Compare``` method even more generic.  I changed the naming as suggested.  Comparing a ```List<>``` to a ```Collection<>``` is fine for me.  Regards.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I wasn't aware of the penalty, but stuck to the original solution presented by Matthew.  These lists are typically in the order of 2 to 4 elements, but in future it could be larger.  For now there is no noticeable difference in speed of all my tests (with fairly large objects), but I will keep the above in mind.  Thanks once again.

Comment: `.Cast<object>()` will cause every `int` (once the `IEnumerable` is consumed, here by `SequenceEquals`) to be boxed. The boxes must be allocated and later removed by the GC. I think this is what makes it slow when you have lists of 100,000 entries. But `dynamic` also has a cost, because overload resolution has to happen at run-time, and is repeated each time. So for very many very short lists, maybe the result is different. (You can also cause the overload binding to fail if you create sufficiently horrible inheritors of `List<>`, but that is maybe not relevant.)

Comment: If anybody cares, here is a relatively small example of "horrible" classes that will make `CompareDynamic<>` above blow up. Define the two types `class Horrible1 : List<DayOfWeek>, IEnumerable<DateTime> { IEnumerator<DateTime> IEnumerable<DateTime>.GetEnumerator() { return Enumerable.Empty<DateTime>().GetEnumerator(); } }` and `class Horrible2 : List<DayOfWeek>, IEnumerable<TimeSpan> { IEnumerator<TimeSpan> IEnumerable<TimeSpan>.GetEnumerator() { return Enumerable.Empty<TimeSpan>().GetEnumerator(); } }`. Then do `List<DayOfWeek> li1 = new Horrible1(); List<DayOfWeek> li2 = new Horrible2();`.

Comment: In fact on my version, the simpler `CompareDynamic(new Horrible1(), new Horrible1())` which needs only one of the classes from the previous comment, also blows up when attempting to bind at run-time.