# How to iterate through a list of classes and use them as generic types?

Tags: c#

I have a list 30 model classes and I have to do the following actions for each class:

```cs
private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
   var odataBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder(serviceProvider);

odataBuilder
 .EntitySet<AnswerCondition>("AnswerConditions")
 .EntityType
 .Select()
 .Expand()
 .OrderBy()
 .Filter()
 .Count();
```

Now I want to have a list of keys-values and do this action inside a for loop:

```
var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, Type>>() {
          new KeyValuePair<string, Type>("ActionTypes", typeof(ActionType)),
          new KeyValuePair<string, Type>("AnswerConditions", typeof(AnswerCondition)),
.
.
.
};

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Type> item in list)
 {
    string address = item.Key;
    Type t = item.Value;
    odataBuilder
     .EntitySet<t>(address)
     .EntityType
     .Select()
     .Expand()
     .OrderBy()
     .Filter()
     .Count();
 }
```

But it shows an error for `t`

> 't' is a variable but is used like a type

How can I store list of classes in a variable and used them later as generic type?

Comment: You can't pass generic types like that. Please, share the code of your `odataBuilder` service.

Comment: I edited the questio

Comment: Could be a related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17519078/initializing-a-generic-variable-from-a-c-sharp-type-variable)! However, I tried and was not any success.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I thought as in the post, you can achieve it via Reflection. But for the `ODataConventionModelBuilder` it might be challenging to use Reflection. I am looking alternative to Reflection.

Comment: The alternative would be a T4 script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Reflection:

```cs
Type oDataType = odataBuilder.GetType();
MethodInfo genericMethod = oDataType.GetMethod("EntitySet", 1, new[] {typeof(string)});

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Type> item in list)
 {
    string address = item.Key;
    Type t = item.Value;
    MethodInfo method = genericMethod.MakeGenericMethod(t);

    dynamic set = method.Invoke(odataBuilder, new object[]{address});
    set
     .EntityType
     .Select()
     .Expand()
     .OrderBy()
     .Filter()
     .Count();
 }
```

Comment: If you know the type at compile time, you don't have to use reflection.

Comment: But if you have a `Type` instance, you can't use it between angle brackets `<>` as a type argument, you have to use reflection.